# Joomla sorting by data, wrong order

Tags: date, sorting, joomla

I have a main page with articles of one category, i set up  sorting by date, in menu,article, and category,  still they are not sorted correctly on my main page, but in the administrator panel, in  view of articles they are sorted properly. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: The sort order for a category blog is set in the menu item's options. Have you cleared any caching?

Comment: its well set, and i tried  other orders, cache are not a problem also.btw in title "date", not data.. missclicked

Comment: try this http://www.joomlablogger.net/joomla-tips/joomla-beginners-tips/how-to-control-article-order-on-the-joomla-front-page/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, my template required me to set "1" for the column number. So, Joomla is in fact ordering correctly, its your template showing them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If a Category is tuned to be shown in several columns (f.e. 2), but only 1 column fits in template, the soring may be broken.